# Will Swype ever be available for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, text-input

[Swype](http://swypeinc.com/index.html) has been rumored to one day become available for iPhone.  Does anyone know of any concrete plans?

Comment: I hadn't seen that before. Very cool!

Comment: Nothing known would be concrete. The features of Apple products are only *known* when *announced*. But I doubt they would use a third-party keyboard. Instead, they would improve their own or create a new one.

Comment: Or at least a dedicated Swype text editor app (if a system-wide keyboard is not possible).

Comment: what does it do? - lol, nevemind. I just found out: http://swypeinc.com/product.html

Comment: Bump.. iOS 13 now has Swype!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2019-09-20**

iOS 13 now has swype-like support built in.

**Pre iOS 13...**

I have been following Swype for some time, and the only thing they have officially said was one little peep in Reuters back in June about looking towards iPhone development.  In the [article](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-sywpe/swype-hits-droid-eyes-iphones-for-future-idUSTRE65N0EX20100624) they alluded towards a developer running Swype on his iPhone, however no releases or leaks are anywhere to be found.

My guess... just a guess... is that they are trying to work around the need to jailbreak your iPhone in order to run it.

If you follow the [Engadget blog](http://www.engadget.com/tag/Swype/), you'll be among the first to know.